# XML encoding error with TimeStamp in Kettle(PDI)

Tags: kettle, pdi

In kettle  Job execution I am maintaining log ,It works fine with everything except "CheckPoints Log Table ".It gives error as "Column_Name Timestamp : there was a value XML encoding error" as Column having datatype DateTime.

Comment: Have you tried checking the datatype of the column_name?. I assume there might be issue in data format. You can try explictly defining the format of the column_name like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Data Type of column is datetime and it should not be alter.

Comment: On the connection settings of your log database try disabling the "database supports timestamp data type" checkbox.

Comment: @nsousa ..Your solutions applied and its working as expected..thanx..